How to Duplicate App on Heroku Dashbaord?
Previously, I could duplicate App from Heroku Dashboard easily but this option is nowhere found. How can I do this now? No reply from Heroku Support to my ticket yet after several days.
Hopefully can get answer here soon, waiting to duplicate an APP.
Checked everywhere on Heroku Dashboard but can't can't find anywhere the Duplicate App function gone.
